# Background textblock on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I want to change background color on TextBlock on Windows phone. Now I've only got a textblock colored without a space near frame. This effect I've got by this code:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="{Binding Color}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="12,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TextBlock** doesn't have a background property on its own. You have to put up a background grid or canvas or border or rectangle to full fill it.

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="100" Background="Blue">
    <TextBlock Name="MyTextBlock" Text="Hello World!" Foreground="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Instead of grid you can make a rectangle or border.

Comment: To have a dynamic string that always has the same "space near frame", remove the width/height from the grid and add margin to text block.

Answer (score 1):

You can also change the background color on the getFocus event like

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TextBox).Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
}
```